# multiple replacement values in python3

Tags: python, replace

I have a few hundred thousand wonky values in a fixed width file.  I want to find the strings old_values and replace them with the strings in the corresponding position in new_values. I could loop through and do this one at a time, but I'm nearly certain there is a much faster way that I am not expert enough to know about.

```
old_values = ('0000}', '0000J', '0000K', '0000L', '0000M', '0000N')  # and many more
new_values = ('   -0', '   -1', '   -2', '   -3', '   -4', '   -5')  # and many more
file_snippet = '00000000000000010000}0000000000000000000200002000000000000000000030000J0000100000000000000500000000000000000000000' # each line is >7K chars long and there are over 6 gigs of text data
```

Looping through each value and running .replace on each line seems slow. eg:

```
for x in len(old_values):
  line.replace(old_values[x], new_values[x])
```

Any tips for speeding things up?

Comment: Please post your current method that is slow.

Comment: How many is "many many more"? Are they all of the same length? Do they all come at the same length offset?

Comment: You will eventually have to iterate through your data if you want to change it.

Comment: Are all of the data broken up into such 5-character values?  If so, you could simply split the data and set up a dictionary to for the old/new values.

Comment: @LennartRegebro About a hundred. And they are all the same length and come at the same offsets (1500 or so variables in a fixed width file).

Comment: @BhajunSingh  They are.  I hadn't thought of that (haven't used dictionaries in python).  But that seems like a good idea. I'll have to learn about dictionaries!

Comment: @Don are you ok to switch to `pypy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is code that will go through the data character by character and replace it if it finds a mapping. This assumes though that each data that needs to be replaced is absolutely unique.

```
def replacer(instring, mapping):

    item = ''

    for char in instring:
        item += char
        yield item[:-5]
        item = item[-5:]
        if item in mapping:
            yield mapping[item]
            item = ''

    yield item


old_values = ('0000}', '0000J', '0000K', '0000L', '0000M', '0000N')
new_values = ('   -0', '   -1', '   -2', '   -3', '   -4', '   -5')
value_map = dict(zip(old_values, new_values))

file_snippet = '00000000000000010000}0000000000000000000200002000000000000000000030000J0000100000000000000500000000000000000000000' # each line is >7K chars long and there are over 6 gigs of text data

result = ''.join(replacer(file_snippet, value_map))
print result
```

On your example data this gives:

```
0000000000000001   -0000000000000000000020000200000000000000000003   -10000100000000000000500000000000000000000000
```

A faster way would be to split the data into 5-character chunks, if the data fits that way:

```
old_values = ('0000}', '0000J', '0000K', '0000L', '0000M', '0000N')
new_values = ('   -0', '   -1', '   -2', '   -3', '   -4', '   -5')
value_map = dict(zip(old_values, new_values))

file_snippet = '00000000000000010000}0000000000000000000200002000000000000000000030000J0000100000000000000500000000000000000000000' # each line is >7K chars long and there are over 6 gigs of text data

result = []
for chunk in [ file_snippet[i:i+5] for i in range(0, len(file_snippet), 5) ]:
    if chunk in value_map:
        result.append(value_map[chunk])
    else:
        result.append(chunk)

result = ''.join(result)
print result
```

This results in no replacements in your example data, unless you remove a leading zero, and then you get:

```
000000000000001   -0000000000000000000020000200000000000000000003   -10000100000000000000500000000000000000000000
```

Same as above.

Answer (score 2):

Making a substitution mapping (`dict`) makes things faster:

```
import timeit

input_string = '00000000000000010000}0000000000000000000200002000000000000000000030000J0000100000000000000500000000000000000000000'
old_values = ('0000}', '0000J', '0000K', '0000L', '0000M', '0000N')
new_values = ('   -0', '   -1', '   -2', '   -3', '   -4', '   -5')
mapping = dict(zip(old_values,new_values))


def test_replace_tuples(input_string, old_values, new_values):
    for x in xrange(len(old_values)):
        input_string = input_string.replace(old_values[x], new_values[x])
    return input_string


def test_replace_mapping(input_string, mapping):
    for k, v in mapping.iteritems():
        input_string = input_string.replace(k, v)
    return input_string


print timeit.Timer('test_replace_tuples(input_string, old_values, new_values)',
                   'from __main__ import test_replace_tuples, input_string, old_values, new_values').timeit(10000)

print timeit.Timer('test_replace_mapping(input_string, mapping)',
                   'from __main__ import test_replace_mapping, input_string, mapping').timeit(10000)
```

prints:

```
0.0547060966492
0.048122882843
```

Note, that the result may be different for different inputs, test it on your real data.

Comment: This small difference is likely to disappear with the real data, which has much larger strings. What you are seeing is likely that the lookup in the tuples take a bit of time. With longer strings that difference will in practice disappear.

Comment: @LennartRegebro good to know, thank you. I was actually thinking about suggesting `pypy`, if it's applicable for the OP, of course..

Comment: Pypy may indeed help, but choosing the right algorithm will help more. :-)